# Mongodb find query with mutiple conditions in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have three working queries:

1. To find the rows with keyword in title field

   ```
   $cursor = $collection->find(['title' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($title_query))])->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1));
   ```
2. To find the rows with keyword in the author field

   ```
   $cursor = $collection->find(['author' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($author_query))])->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1));
   ```
3. To find the rows within a date range

   ```
   $rangeQuery = array('timestamp' => array( '$gte' => $from_Id, '$lte' => $to_Id ));

   $cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery)->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1));
   ```

I want to combine the queries into 1&2, 1&3 and 2&3. However I am not able to write the correct query...

Here is my query for combining 1&2:

```
    $cursor = $collection->find('title' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($title_query)),
           'author' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($author_query)))->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1));
```

query for combining 1&3:

```
     $rangeQuery = array('timestamp' => array( '$gte' => $from_Id, '$lte' => $to_Id ));
     $cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery, ['title' => array('$regex'=>new MongoRegex($title_query))])->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1));
```

Can anyone tell me how to write the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator should not be necessary if you are using the BSON regex type (i.e. MongoRegex in the PHP driver). Let's rewrite the original three queries:

1. Matching keyword in title, sorted by time descending:

   ```
   $collection->find([
     'title' => new MongoRegex($title_query),
   ])->sort(['timestamp' => -1]);
   ```
2. Matching keyword in author, sorted by time descending:

   ```
   $collection->find([
     'author' => new MongoRegex($author_query),
   ])->sort(['timestamp' => -1]);
   ```
3. Matching within a date range, sorted by time descending:

   ```
   $collection->find([
     'timestamp' => [
       '$gte' => $from_Id,
       '$lte' => $to_Id,
     ],
   ])->sort(['timestamp' => -1]);
   ```

There are several errors in the combined query examples you shared in the OP. For the "1&2" query, you were not passing an array as the first argument to `find()`, so that would have been a syntax error. For the "1&3" query, you're only passing the timestamp range as `find()` criteria, and the title regex is being incorrected passed as the second `find()` argument, which is reserved for specifying a project (i.e. which fields to return).

Combining the three queries is actually as easy as merging the criteria arrays. For example, we could combine all three like so:

```
$collection->find([
  'title' => new MongoRegex($title_query),
  'author' => new MongoRegex($author_query),
  'timestamp' => [
    '$gte' => $from_Id,
    '$lte' => $to_Id,
  ],
])->sort(['timestamp' => -1]);
```

In some cases, it's not possible to merge criteria for the same field. For that reason, MongoDB has an [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) query operator (see the examples for some use cases); however, in the examples above, the criteria is simple enough that you can simply combine the arrays.

Comment: Thank you it worked. however, when I tried to put the query inside the string , it does not produce any result. For instance $query = "['title' => new MongoRegex($title_query),]". Then I go, $cursor = $collection->find($query). What is the problem here?

Comment: If you consult the documentation for [`MongoCollection::find()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php), you'll see that it expects the query criteria to be an array. MongoDB uses BSON objects (e.g. associative arrays in PHP) for query criteria, not strings like you might find in drivers for SQL databases. The query structure is discussed a bit more in [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).

Comment: Thank you!  you are a great help to me !